# Program never gets to the part where I can input information

Tags: c++, while-loop, text-files, ifstream

When I run the program the output window prints out the line "! Loading Data..." but it seems it's stuck in a loop endlessly. As far as I can tell the while loop is set up correctly, but after plugging away I am at a loss.

```
ifstream myfile("Data.CS.txt");

if (!myfile) { //Always test the file open. 
    cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}
cout << endl;
cout << "! Loading Data...";
while (getline(myfile, line)) {
    string delimiter = "|";
    string delimiter2 = "-=>";

    size_t pos = 0;
    string tempLine;
    string tokenName;

    string token;
    string token2;

    vector <string> storeTokenPairs;

    tokenName = line.substr(0, pos);
    tempLine = line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());

    while ((pos = tempLine.find(delimiter2)) != string::npos) {
        token = tempLine.substr(0, pos);
        storeTokenPairs.push_back(token);
        line.erase(0, pos + delimiter2.length());

    }
    for (int i=0; i<storeTokenPairs.size(); i++)
        dictionary.emplace(tokenName, make_pair(storeTokenPairs[i], storeTokenPairs[i+1]));
}
```

Comment: wow, I can't believe I didn't see this. So then I need to change it to tempLine.erase

Comment: @javaNoob please don't edit the question like you did. You changed the semantics of the code, invalidating the comments given.  I have reverted your edit.  If you want, you can post your own answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code is wrong:

```
 while ((pos = tempLine.find(delimiter2)) != string::npos) {
    token = tempLine.substr(0, pos);
    storeTokenPairs.push_back(token);
    line.erase(0, pos + delimiter2.length()); // <-- HERE
}
```

You are never modifying `tempLine`, so the loop runs endlessly if `delimiter2` is found in `tempLine`.

You need to replace `line` with `tempLine` instead:

```
tempLine.erase(0, pos + delimiter2.length());
```

Alternatively, you don't actually need to modify `tempLine` at all, as `find()` takes an optional start index as input:

```
size_t start = 0, pos;

while ((pos = tempLine.find(delimiter2, start)) != string::npos) {
    token = tempLine.substr(start, pos-start);
    storeTokenPairs.push_back(token);
    start = pos + delimiter2.length();
}

if (start < tempLine.length()) {
    token = tempLine.substr(start);
    storeTokenPairs.push_back(token);
}
```